# How to go from MainActivity to Fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-menu

I launched android studio and created a new project (File-> New-> Navigation drawer activity) and added some useful codes for myself. Now my code is working fine. But there are problems in the code. I created one menu button in the toolbar and wrote the code for this menu button.

main.xml(menu->main.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:title="Spinning"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#000000"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_cart"
        android:icon="@drawable/card"
        android:title="Cart"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/custom_action_item_layout"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

custom_action_item_layout.xml(for main.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:focusable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/card"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cart_badge"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|end|top"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/badge_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="10sp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Result**

[image]

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MyToolMenu = menu;
        final MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart);

        View actionView = menuItem.getActionView();

        actionView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //Action button BASKET

                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), fragment_order.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error:"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
            }
        });
```

**Toast shows an error:**

> `unable to find explicit activity class{} have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xm`

I want to go to fragments_order  when I press the menu button and this code is written in MainActivity. Where is my mistake why the intent is not working and how to fix this error?

Comment: You should read some basics ... fragments are not activieties and cannot be changed via Intents ... use fragment manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you most use fragmentManager to change fragments.
Intent is used to start Activity , Service
you can replace fragment like this:

```
Fragment1 f1 = new Fragment1();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.f1_container, f1); // f1_container is your FrameLayout 
container
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

and you can start activity like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: error: incompatible types: fragment_order cannot be converted to Fragment

Answer (score 0):

what is `fragment_order.class`? I bet it isn't `Activity`, so you got `unable to find explicit activity class` exception. `Fragment != Activity`

some doc about `Fragment`s in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)

in case `fragment_order` is an `Activity` then:

1. change this name
2. just like your `Toast` says: declare in `AndroidManifest` this `Activty`

Comment: fragment_order it is fragment.

Comment: so you can't use `startActivity`, as it is not an `Activity`... read some doc (linked in answer) to get to know how to handle `Fragment`s. in short you need to use `FragmentManager` and `FragmentTransaction` to attach `Fragment` to already started and running `Activity` (some container inside its layout to be exact)